# Проблема установки "pillow"(python)

Tags: python

возникла проблема с установкой "pillow", выдается такая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3880qmbs\pillow\setup.py", line 907, in 
>           raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>       **main**.RequiredDependencyException:
>
> The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required
>   dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
> Please see the install instructions at:
>   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
> Command
>   "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u
>   -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3880qmbs\pillow\
>   \setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
>   open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Temp \pip-record-nwaxq2os\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\include\site\python3.8\pillow"
>   failed wi th error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3880qmbs\pillow\

Команду ввел такую:
"pip3 install pillow"

Comment: Это точно полный текст ошибки?

Comment: @andreymal, дополнил)

Comment: Попробуйте `pip install --only-binary Pillow Pillow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Был/есть баг с 3.8.

Краткое содержание:
попробовать

```
pip install Pillow==6.2.1 --no-cache-dir # или pip3
```

Возможно придется сменить версию pip на 19.3

```
pip install pip==19.3
```

Comment: При первом такая же ошибка, а при втором выдает новую) 
вот ошибка(вкратце, могу залить на сторонний ресурс):
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'

Comment: Помогла продвинуться дальше вот эта команда:
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip